# Host name url regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are many RegExs out there for URLs etc, but I'm really stumped as to why this one wont work. I'm trying to make sure a user's entry is a proper web site, allowing for either www or not.

```
var pattern = 
/http(s?):\/\/                      (http:// or https://)
(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.){0,1}                (0 or 1 instance of www)
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1}     (1 instance of a domain name)
(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/;              (1 or more instance of .com or .co.uk)
```

It works for the following testcases using pattern.test()

- http://www.stackoverflow.com -> true
- http://stackoverflow.com -> true
- https://stackoverflow.com -> true
- htts://stackoverflow.com -> false
- http:/stackoverflow.com -> false

However, even though I explicitly tell the regex it must match the .com or .co.uk, etc. it allows me to write such nonsense as:

- http://www.stackoverflow -> true (wrong)
- http://www.stackoverflow. -> true (wrong)
- http://www.stackoverflow.c -> true (wrong)

I've been wracking my brain trying different combos but I can understand why even though I explicitly say there must be one or more domain extension, that portion doesn't seem to matter?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re trying to *validate* a string, you need to anchor it to the beginning and end of the string:

```
var pattern = 
/^http(s?):\/\/                      (http:// or https://)
(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.){0,1}                (0 or 1 instance of www)
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+){1}     (1 instance of a domain name)
(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+$/;              (1 or more instance of .com or .co.uk)
```

For `www.stackoverflow`, the first group isn’t matching (because you said it’s optional), then the second group is matching `www`, and the third group is matching `.stacko`.

Tips:

- `{1}` is not necessary
- `{0,1}` is equivalent to `?`
- Since you’re not using any captures, `(s?)` could just be `s?`